# How can i create user with custom domain in Entra ID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-entra-id, azure-entra-id

I am trying to create a user in my entra id using `Microsoft.Graph`. Its letting me create a user with my tenent domain but not with a custom domain. I tried Identities for custom domain then its giving error `Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Property creationType is invalid`.

I also saw similar issues here on stack overflow but they all ended up here cant find anything to fix `creationType` error

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

I tried this on which which its saying `Property creationType is invalid.`

```
var requestBody = new User
{
    DisplayName = "John Smith",
    Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
    {
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "userName",
            Issuer = "contoso.com",
            IssuerAssignedId = "johnsmith",
        },
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "emailAddress",
            Issuer = "contoso.com",
            IssuerAssignedId = "jsmith@yahoo.com",
        },
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "federated",
            Issuer = "facebook.com",
            IssuerAssignedId = "5eecb0cd",
        },
    },
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = "password-value",
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
    },
    PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
};

var result = await graphClient.Users.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Also when i remove these objects, it says `Property accountEnabled value is required but is empty or missing` then `MailNickname` and then `UserPrincipalName`:

```
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "userName",
            Issuer = "spectrumdevtest.onmicrosoft.com",
            IssuerAssignedId = "johnsmith",
        },
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "federated",
            Issuer = "facebook.com",
            IssuerAssignedId = "5eecb0cd",
        },
```

I also added `CreationType="LocalAccount"` then its saying `Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Name coexistence user creation is not enabled on tenant. paramName: company.DirectoryFeatures, paramValue: ,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [creating a user via Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/how-to-create-delete-users#basics), we can choose to `enter a unique username and select a domain from the menu after the @ symbol`, so that we need to [create a custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/add-custom-domain) in advance. Using [this Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-post-domains?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create custom domain then create user can solve OP's issue.

================================

Each user we created in Azure Entra Id will display in the `All Users` and just like what you can see, user principle name can in these format `username@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com` which is for users created directly and `userName_outlook.com#EXT#@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com`.

[image]

We can use `userName@outlook.com` to sign into Azure portal and switch to target tenant if this account has accessibility to several tenants, but it is created a corresponding account `userName_outlook.com#EXT#@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com` essentially. The same for using Graph API to create user account.

By the way, creating external account is using ["invite feature"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) essentially.

[image]

Comment: Yeah we can invite johndoe@outlook.com, also gsuite accounts after setting up google federation but what I'm trying is that I be able to "create" account in my tenant but not with my tenant domain "...onmicrosoft.com" instead like "johndoe@xyzcompany.com"

Comment: do you mean, you want to use graph api to create a user, which can use `johndoe@xyzcompany.com` to sign in? even if this account is `johndoe_xyzcompany.com#EXT#@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com`?

Comment: I'm not very sure whether I understood your requirement correctly, but based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/how-to-create-delete-users#basics), we can `enter a unique username and select a domain from the menu after the @ symbol. Select Domain not listed if you need to create a new domain`, so that we need to [add custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/add-custom-domain),

Comment: If this is what you want to achieve, then I'm afraid we have to use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-post-domains?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) at the same time so that we could use the custom domain when creating the user.

Comment: Yeah I found it in the documentation that for a custom domain, I'll have to create a domain in my tenant and then verify it before assigning to user.

Comment: @wasihyder  could you pls update here whether the 2 APIs helped or not? thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry didnt got what you mean

Comment: oh sorry for the puzzling expression, I just want to know whether the "create custom domain" api and the "create user" api helped to solve your issue or not.

Comment: Yeah, first we'll have a to create a custom domain then when creating user we'll assign that to the user. thanks

Comment: thank you for your kind reply.  I trust this issue is resolved now.